# snowflake temp table connection using JDBC

Tags: jdbc, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, mybatis, websphere-liberty, snowflake-schema

I am trying to put temp values in the snowflake temporary table using Mybatis. Connection details configured at WebSphere Application server's server.xml file.

Ideally values should be retained at server request level.

**But as long as application running , Temp table and its data remains available. With every request I am able to see previous insert data.**

Same code is working fine for Oracle global temp table.

```
public class TempDao{

@Inject
SqlSession sqlSession;

public int saveValues(List<TemporaryValue> values) {
        logger.debug("Saving items on temporary table");
        try {
            final Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<>();
            parameters.put("jobList", values);
            return sqlSession.insert("com.some.sql.insertJobs", parameters);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            ExceptionUtils.propagate(e);
        }
        return 0;
    }


}
```

JNDI Connection:

```
<dataSource id="SnowflakeDataSource" jndiName="jdbc/BM_SF" maxPoolSize="100" queryTimeout="300s" statementCacheSize="1000" type="javax.sql.DataSource">
        <properties URL="jdbc:snowflake://adpdc_cdl.us-east-1.privatelink.snowflakecomputing.com" databaseName="***" password="****" schema="**" user="**" warehouse="****strong text**" />
        <jdbcDriver javax.sql.DataSource="net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeBasicDataSource" libraryRef="SharedLib"/>
    </dataSource>
```

Comment: What exactly is the issue? Snowflake temporary tables are available for the period of the session in which they were created. They are destroyed when the session is terminated.

Comment: Yea, what is your question?

Comment: Even if I am closing the JDBC connection when a request is completed, Temp table is not getting destroyed. Unless I restart my application server. Is there any more settings that needs to be done or am I missing something?

Comment: How are you closing the JDBC connection, can you provide an example?

Comment: it sounds like you have connection pooling in your code, so the session is being reused (to save connection setup time) and thus your temporary table is living longer than you expect.

Comment: Yeah DB Session ID is same for all connections in the connection pool. Seems some issue with snowflake JDBC driver.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to turn off connection pooling in Liberty if it interferes with the ending of sessions in Snowflake. See the connectionManager element with agedTimeout of 0 (immediate timeout) that I inserted to your config snippet,

```
    <dataSource id="SnowflakeDataSource" jndiName="jdbc/BM_SF" maxPoolSize="100" queryTimeout="300s" statementCacheSize="1000" type="javax.sql.DataSource">
        <connectionManager agedTimeout="0"/>
        <properties URL="jdbc:snowflake://adpdc_cdl.us-east-1.privatelink.snowflakecomputing.com" databaseName="***" password="****" schema="**" user="**" warehouse="****strong text**" />
        <jdbcDriver javax.sql.DataSource="net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeBasicDataSource" libraryRef="SharedLib"/>
    </dataSource>
```

Comment: thank you @njr . Now it is working. But in production switching off connection pooling is definitely not a good option